# Java - Method in an interface that can take any subclass?

Tags: java, events, generics

So, I'm making an interface for some event stuff I've been playing with lately, so far it's looked like.

```
public interface Handler {

    void handle(Class<? extends Event> event);
```

}

and

```
public interface Handler<T super Event> {

    void handle(T event);
```

}

Neither of these will take a subclass of Event without it telling me to make the implementing class abstract. Is there something I can do about this, or am I forced into abstraction?

Comment: Second one should work fine if you parameterize the `implements` target type. Don't use raw types.

Answer (score 1):

> Neither of these will take a subclass of Event

You appear to be avoiding the most obvious solution which will solve you problem.

```
public interface Handle {
    void handle(Event event);
}
```

or

```
public interface Handle<T extends Event> {
    void handle(T event);
}
```

or in Java 8 you would use the built in.

```
Consumer<Event>
```